# Can I put conditional expressions inside multi-line strings in groovy?

Tags: groovy, multiline

For example, given the following:

```
"""
 {
   "a": "$a",
   "b": "$b",
   "c": "$c"
 }
"""
```

How can I stop it from including the last line ("c":"$c") if $c is null?

Answer (score 2):

That's going to be not so nice looking:

```
"""
     {
       "a": "$a",
       "b": "$b"${c != null ? ',\n       "c": "' + c + '"' : '' }
     }
"""
```

this if you need same formatting.

Or else, in more readable form:

```
"""
 {
   "a": "$a",
   "b": "$b"
   ${c != null ? ', "c": "' + c + '"' : '' }
 }
"""
```

Comment: Ended up doing this:"""
 {
   "a": "$a",
   "b": "$b",
    ${c==null?"":""",c": "$c"""}
 }
"""  - seems to work

Answer (score 2):

Or, as you're writing json;

```
def map = [a:a, b:b] + (c != null ? [c:c] : [:])
String json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(​​​​​​​​​map)​
```